# Dynamic table output in bash with markers from associative array

Tags: bash, shell

I've created a small script which takes an associative array as input like follows:

```bash
declare -A componentMatrix=(
  ["Component 1"    ]='debug,sysinstall,install,configure,deploy'
  ["Component 2"    ]='install,configure,smoketest,sysuninstall'
  ["Component 1234" ]='install,debug,dummy,showlogs'
  ["Component 32"   ]='install,sysuninstall,showlogs'
  ["Component 666"  ]='sysinstall,configure,showlogs'
)
```

and creates a table like this:

```
                 | showlogs     | dummy        | debug        | smoketest    | install      | configure    | deploy       | sysinstall   | sysuninstall |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
Component 32     |       *      |              |              |              |       *      |              |              |              |       *      |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
Component 2      |              |              |              |       *      |       *      |       *      |              |              |       *      |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
Component 1      |              |              |       *      |              |       *      |       *      |       *      |       *      |              |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
Component 1234   |       *      |       *      |       *      |              |       *      |              |              |              |              |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
Component 666    |       *      |              |              |              |       *      |       *      |              |       *      |              |
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The widths are automatically calculated, and the asterisks are roughly placed in the middle. It features an offset option to move the table horizontally (x-axis).

This works pretty well; however, the resulting code seems overly complex to me:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A componentMatrix=(
  ["Component 1"    ]='debug,sysinstall,install,configure,deploy'
  ["Component 2"    ]='install,configure,smoketest,sysuninstall'
  ["Component 1234" ]='install,debug,dummy,showlogs'
  ["Component 32"   ]='install,sysuninstall,showlogs'
  ["Component 666"  ]='sysinstall,configure,showlogs'
)

show_component_table() {
  declare -A unique_cmds          # Associative array to keep track of unique commands
  local offset=${1:?}             # Offset variable to move the table to the right
  local max_component_length=0    # Variable to store the maximum length of components
  local max_cmd_length=0          # Variable to store the maximum length of commands
  local horizontal_line_char="-"  # Character used for horizontal line
  local vertical_char="|"         # Character used for vertical line
  local intersection_char="+"     # Character used for intersections
  local asterisk_char="*"         # Character used to indicate command presence
  local component cmds cmd

  generate_horizontal_line() {
    printf "%*s" $offset
    for ((i=0; i<${first_col_width}; i++)); do
      printf "$horizontal_line_char"
    done
    printf "$intersection_char"
    for ((i=0; i<${#cmdlist[@]}; i++)); do
      for ((j=0; j<$generic_col_width; j++)); do
        printf "$horizontal_line_char"
      done
      printf "$intersection_char"
    done
    echo ""
  }

  for component in "${!componentMatrix[@]}"; do
    if (( ${#component} > max_component_length )); then
      max_component_length=${#component}
    fi
    cmds=${componentMatrix[$component]}
    for cmd in ${cmds//,/ }; do
      # Mark the command as encountered
      unique_cmds[$cmd]=1
    done
  done

  # Extract unique commands from the associative array keys
  local cmdlist=("${!unique_cmds[@]}")

  # Determine the maximum length of a command
  for cmd in "${cmdlist[@]}"; do
    if (( ${#cmd} > max_cmd_length )); then
      max_cmd_length=${#cmd}
    fi
  done

  # Calculate column widths
  local generic_col_width=$((max_cmd_length + 2))
  local first_col_width=$((max_component_length + 2))
  local mid_component=$(((generic_col_width) / 2))
  local rest_component=$((generic_col_width - mid_component))

  # Print header row with commands
  printf "%*s" $offset
  # Empty cell for component column
  printf "%-${first_col_width}s|" ""
  for cmd in "${cmdlist[@]}"; do
    printf " %-${max_cmd_length}s ${vertical_char}" "$cmd"
  done
  echo ""

  # Print horizontal line after header row
  generate_horizontal_line

  # Print table
  for component in "${!componentMatrix[@]}"; do
    printf "%*s" $offset
    printf "%-${first_col_width}s|" "$component"
    cmds=${componentMatrix[$component]}
    for cmd in "${cmdlist[@]}"; do
      if [[ $cmds =~ $cmd ]]; then
        printf " %${mid_component}s%${rest_component}s" "$asterisk_char" "${vertical_char}"
      else
        printf "%-${generic_col_width}s%s" "" "${vertical_char}"
      fi
    done
    echo ""

    # Print horizontal line between component rows
    generate_horizontal_line
  done
}

show_component_table 10
```

I was wondering if there is an easier, more elegant way to achieve this in bash.

Maybe there even exists a tool which does this (should be available as a standalone, with no dependencies on other script languages, like python, perl, javascript, etc).

Or perhaps there are some bash features which could simplify this approach of mine.

Comment: calculate `max_cmd_length` in the same loop while populating `unique_cmds[]`; first time you print the horizontal line consider first saving the final line in a variable and then on repeat function calls just print the whole-line variable (eliminate the repeated loop processing each time you print the *same* horizontal line), and similar concept for horizontal line for the 2nd-nth columns -> they're the same width so figure out 2nd column's `-----` and then duplicate (as opposed to re-printing a series of `-` for 3rd-nth columns)

Comment: for performance purposes consider a different tool geared more towards text processing (eg, `awk`, `perl`, `python`); primary objective being to get away from all of the OS-level commands the `bash` script has to invoke

Comment: I just whipped up a simple perl script that does this (Via the [`Text::Table::Tiny` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table::Tiny). Much simpler than your script. Can provide it if desired.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `column` utility.

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the input, I'll look into that loop aspect. Performance is not an issue, we're talking about a small table which will be dynamically built once per call invocation (which happens at most minutely). This is part of a larger script framework for DevOps purposes, hence no additional dependency on other scripting languages is preferred; besides that `perl` is not installed.

Comment: @Shawn Cool tool, however I don't see how it could reproduce my table based on the input I provide. Additionally, the target nodes have no `perl` installed and this script is a tiny cog in a set of shell scripts of DevOps people. The `column` utility I know, but I didn't really figure out how to map my structure to a useful input for it. It's probably the one thing I'd consider, if I figure out how to map my input structure to a suitable output structure.

Comment: Spaces in this case are part of the key `["Component 1234" ]` so in your example key widths are constant.

Comment: @LMC Sure, it's just an example. My inquiry remains, though.

Comment: @ikaerom did you have a chance to take a look at the answer?

Comment: @LMC not yet to the degree I wanted to. By trade, I'm a lawyer with lots of traveling engagements ;). This is a hobby I started in the late 80s when I discovered Unix. I'll get to it. I noticed a couple of useless forks, which I'd definitely write differently.

Comment: Yes, the output of `uniq_cmds_sorted` can be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is an option using `awk` to get string length and half length. Makes heavy use of `printf "%*.*s" <padding length> <padding limit> <value>`

```
#!/bin/bash

# all commands
uniq_cmds(){
  for x in "${!componentMatrix[@]}";do
    printf "%s\n" "${componentMatrix[$x]}" | tr ',' '\n'
  done
}

# unique commands, sorted. Also command length and half length
uniq_cmds_sorted(){
  uniq_cmds | sort | uniq | awk '{ len=length($0); half=len/2 ; printf "%d %d %s\n", half, len, $0 | "sort -rn -k2,2" }'
}

declare -A componentMatrix=(
  ["Component1"]='debug,sysinstall,install,configure,deploy'
  ["Component2"]='install,configure,smoketest,sysuninstall'
  ["Component 1234"]='install,debug,dummy,showlogs'
  ["Component 32"]='install,sysuninstall,showlogs'
  ["Component 666"]='sysinstall,configure,showlogs'
)

# longest array key length
lkey=$(printf '%s\n' "${!componentMatrix[@]}" | awk '{ print length($0) | "sort -rn | head -n1" }')


# heading with sorted commands
heading=$(
printf " %*.*s " $lkey $lkey ' '
uniq_cmds_sorted | while read -a parts; do
   printf "| %-*.*s " ${parts[1]} ${parts[1]} "${parts[2]}"
done)

# row separator
separ=$(
printf " %*.*s%s" $lkey $lkey '-' '+'
uniq_cmds_sorted | while read -a parts; do
   printf "%*s%s" ${parts[1]} ' ' "--+"
done)
fsep="$(printf "%s\n" " ${separ// /-}")"

# matrix content
yesno=$(
for x in "${!componentMatrix[@]}"; do 
  # print first cell
  printf " %*.*s " $lkey $lkey "$x"
  uniq_cmds_sorted | while read -a parts; do
    val=' '
    # mark matched commands in current array value
    if grep -q "\b${parts[2]}\b" <<<"${componentMatrix[$x]}"; then
      # to print a check mark ✔
      #val="$(echo -e '\u2714')"
      val='*'
    fi
    if (( ${parts[1]} % ${parts[0]} )); then
      val="$val "
    fi
    
    # print a single cell without a line ending
    printf "| %*.*s%s%*.*s" ${parts[0]} ${parts[0]} " " "${val}" ${parts[0]} ${parts[0]} " "
  done
  # close the row
  echo "|"
  echo "$fsep"
done
)


printf "%s|\n" "$heading"
echo "$fsep"
printf "%s\n" "$yesno"
```

Result

```
               | sysuninstall | sysinstall | smoketest | configure | showlogs | install | deploy | dummy | debug |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
 Component1234 |              |            |           |           |     *    |    *    |        |   *   |   *   |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
    Component2 |       *      |            |     *     |     *     |          |    *    |        |       |       |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
    Component1 |              |      *     |           |     *     |          |    *    |    *   |       |   *   |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
  Component666 |              |      *     |           |     *     |     *    |         |        |       |       |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
   Component32 |       *      |            |           |           |     *    |    *    |        |       |       |
 --------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably off-topic since this doesn't use Bash nor associative arrays, but here's a suggestion in SH.

```
#! /bin/sh

set -o nounset

show_component_table()
  {
  local PresenceMarker='*'
  local HorizChar='-'
  local VertChar='|'
  local InterChar='+'   # intersection character
  local Offset=''       # table left margin
  local MaxLength_C     # components maxlength
  local MaxLength_H     # headers maxlength
  local EmptyCell
  local FirstLine
  local SepLine         # rows separating line
  local Headers
  local Name
  local Values
  local Arg
  local Field

  while test "$#" -gt 0
  do    case "$1" in (-PresenceMarker=*|-HorizChar=*|-VertChar=*|-InterChar=*|-Offset=*)
                         Arg="${1#-}"
                         eval "${Arg%%=*}=\"\${Arg#*=}\""
                         shift ;;
                     (-*)
                         echo "unknow option: \"${1%%=*}\"" >&2
                         exit 1 ;;
                     (*)
                         break ;;
        esac
  done

  Headers="$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sed -e 's/.*=//; s/,/\n/g' | sort | uniq)"

  MaxLength_C="$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sed -e 's/=.*//' | wc -L)"
  
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086
  MaxLength_H="$(printf '%s\n' $Headers | wc -L)"

  PresenceMarker="$(printf '%.*s\n' "$MaxLength_H" "$(printf '%*s%s%*s' "$(( (MaxLength_H - ${#PresenceMarker}) / 2  ))" '' "$PresenceMarker" "$MaxLength_H" '')")"

  EmptyCell="$(printf '%*s' "$MaxLength_H" '')"
  
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086
  FirstLine="$(printf "%*s ${VertChar}" "$MaxLength_C" ''; printf " %-${MaxLength_H}s ${VertChar}" $Headers)"

  SepLine="${Offset}$(printf '%s' "$FirstLine" | tr -c "$VertChar" "$HorizChar" | tr "$VertChar" "$InterChar")"

  printf '%s\n' "${Offset}$FirstLine" "$SepLine"
  
  for Arg
  do  Name="${Arg%%=*}"
      Values="${Arg#*=}"
      printf "%s%-*s ${VertChar}" "$Offset" "$MaxLength_C" "$Name"
      for Field in $Headers
      do  case ",$Values," in (*,$Field,*)   printf " %s ${VertChar}" "$PresenceMarker" ;;
                                       (*)   printf " %s ${VertChar}" "$EmptyCell" ;;
          esac
      done
      printf '\n%s\n' "$SepLine"
  done
  }

show_component_table 'Component 1=debug,sysinstall,install,configure,deploy' \
                     'Component 2=install,configure,smoketest,sysuninstall'  \
                     'Component 1234=install,debug,dummy,showlogs'           \
                     'Component 32=install,sysuninstall,showlogs'            \
                     'Component 666=sysinstall,configure,showlogs'
```